# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Inspiron 5548 - Ubuntu works fine with Live USB but after installation run in low resolution/graphics mode

Tags: partitioning, amd-graphics

I have Dell Inspiron 15 5548 laptop. 64 bit system. 1TB hard disk, 8GB Ram, 2GB ATI Radeon M265 Graphics card with Intel onboard HD graphics 5500 (Broadwll GT2).

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on one EXT4 partition of 100GB

The hard disk is partitioned as follows:

- 1GB FAT32 for efi partion
- 100GB ExT4 for Ubuntu 14.04.2 64bit
- 100GB EXT4 for data like documents
- 780GB for movies music etc
- 8.8 GB for swap

After installing Ubuntu, when I start my laptop, it shows

> Graphics not detected

when I click <kbd>OK</kbd>

It gives me 4 options:

1. Boot into low resolution mode for 1 session
2. Reconfigure graphics
3. Troubleshoot the error
4. Console login

But I am stuck at the first option and can't select any of the other three. Using <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't highlight the other options; they just highlight the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> or <kbd>OK</kbd> buttons. I cannot see the mouse cursor on this screen.

If I select Low Resolution mode, system tells me to stand by for 1 minute with <kbd>OK</kbd> button below. If I stand by without selecting on <kbd>OK</kbd> nothing happens even after 5 minutes. If I select <kbd>OK</kbd> then I get a black screen and again nothing happens or appears on screen.

The system works in normal resolution and works fine in Live USB mode.

When the laptop came with windows 8.1 preinstalled, I installed Ubuntu on second partition of 50GB. That time it worked fine without problem.

After that I completely formatted my hard disk (also deleted Backup/recovery partitions of Windows as I want to install Ubuntu as single system) and installed Ubuntu as described at start of this problem and now I am getting this error.

The system works fine in Live USB mode.

Is this happening because I am using GPT partitioning?

Strange Thing Happened... I installed Ubuntu by choosing erase entire disk and install Ibuntu with encryption and LVM option and it works without problem. But the problem is with encryption you only have a single DISK so in future while updating Ubuntu, data may get deleted...

Also when I choose to install Ubuntu on entire disk without encryption, it works without problem.

Comment: Use the arrow keys rather than tab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Comment: Try to boot in failsafex and install fglrx.

Comment: arrow keys are also not working

Comment: Strange Thing Happened... I installed Ubuntu by choosing erase entire disk and install ubuntu with encryption and LVM option and it works without problem. But the problem is with encryption you only have single DISK so in future while updating ubuntu, data may get deleted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

As I mentioned above Ubuntu works fine when installed on Hard Disk with Single Partition using "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" (1st option in Installation Window. During the installation an EFI partition (537MB) and Swap Partition (8.5GB) are created automatically.

After trying multiple combinations I partitioned my disk as follows:

I deleted all partitions on my hard disk (partitions I created during previous installation attempts).

Then, I created the partition for installing Ubuntu (100GB) at the start of the disk.

Next, I created 1GB FAT32 partition for EFI to right of 100GB Ubuntu Partition. (FAT32 is required and EXT3 or EXT4 will not work. And actually as told by Pilot6 to me 1GB space is not required. Anything between 550MB to 600MB is sufficient)

Then I left all the remaining space as "Free Space" and selected to install Ubuntu on 1st Partition and selected the Complete Hard Disk (not 1st 100GB partition) to install bootloader.

After installation I partitioned the remaining 800-900GB using Gnome Disk Utility in Ubuntu (shown as simply DISKS in launcher).

Also after installation I installed the drivers for my graphics card from **Additional Drivers**.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Ubuntu search in system settings for 'Additional Drivers' or something like that. In that panel you can search for missing drivers. Often nVidia or ATI drivers are not open source and their drivers must be manually installed. See that link 'https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD'

Comment: He can't get into the system.